# Unit testing endpoint protected by In-memory Authentication Engine

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I'm using stateless authentication in CakePHP3 provided by [ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth](https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth). I configured Auth component to use the memory storage.

In the IntegrationTestCase I set

```
$this->session([
        'Auth' => [
            'User' => [
                'id' => 100,
                ...
            ]
        ]
]);
```

But the test always fails, because the auth component is not searching the user data in the session. Is there a way to bypass authentication when using memory storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not searching in the session because JWT is *not* using the session. That's the whole point of a token based [stateless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) auth system. It's explained [here](http://jwt.io/) as well.

You need to get and send the token along with your request.

I would recommend you to get an understanding of how things work *before* implementing them, especially when it comes to authentication and authorization or other security related topics. Otherwise this can end up in security holes and funky bugs.

Comment: The whole point is bo bypass authorisation for unittesting only.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a answer marked as accepted, but I think the person who created the question was talking about how to bypass the authentication when using JWT based authentication, so here is my answer for that discovered in the tests of ADmad himself:

```
<?php
    $token = JWT::encode(['sub' => 1], Security::salt());

    $this->configRequest([
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token
        ]
    ]);
?>
```

Basically, if you do that before each request you can bypass authentication.